# Call a Java class through Java Script

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I have spent the recent hours looking all over the net for an answer for this, but nothing has helped me so far, so I thought I'd ask my own question here.

So to make a long story short, I want to call a Java class/method from my webpage, and I have understood that AJAX is the best method, through the use of JS, the java class and a .jsp file. Although, I have only been able to parse the content of the .jsp file so far

Here's my html (and JS) file (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Such wow</title>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  console.log("loadDoc is running");
  $.ajax({
                  url : 'test.jsp', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                  type : 'POST',
                  dataType : 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
                  success : function(response) {
                    console.log(response+" = response");
                      $('#outputDiv').html(response); // create an empty div in your page with some id
                  },
                  error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert(errorThrown);
                  }
              });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the .jsp file (test.jsp)

```
<body>
<%
  Test tc = new Test();
  out.print(tc.getString());
%>
</body>
```

And last, but not least, the actual Java file (Test.java)

```
public class Test {
      public static void main(String args[])
         {
            Test obj = new Test();
             String temp1= obj.getString();
         }
      public String getString(String hey, String yo){
        return "Heyya, " + yo + "  --  " +hey;
      }
    }
```

So as I said, this only logs the content of the .jsp file in the console. I want to actually call the getString method of Test.java. I have compiled the Java file in the file system, so that should not be the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: First you need to setup a server which can execute your jsp files, take a look at this for an introduction: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JSPByExample.html

Comment: @emed I have now installed Tomcat on my system (Raspberry Pi) and it seems more promising, your link example worked! Will be trying again in like 15 hours.

Thanks for the help, so far!